# Conditional Expectation with 2 distributions

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution

you could help me with this problem I would really appreciate it. This is not a task just an exercise to understand the subject.
Let the random variable $X \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(p)$. Suppose that given an $X = i$, $Y$ is a random variable of type $\mathrm{Poisson} (3 (i + 1))$. Find $\mathbb{E} \left[(X +1) Y^2\right]$.

Comment: Weirdest title I've seen here in a while.

Comment: In some languages, the word for "expectation" could be translated to "hope". Of course, this is a bad translation (in this context).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I guess the OP is Italian or French. We use the term *speranza* / *ésperance* (i.e. *hope*) to denote the expected value.

Comment: @Jack: Well, I expect that it's not unreasonable to hope that people use the correct English term regardless. Or maybe I hope it's not unreasonable to expect. I'm not which one, and for Italian people, I guess that would be interchangeable anyway. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
 E[(X+1)Y^2] 
 &= E[E[(X+1)Y^2|X]] \\
 &= E[(X+1)E[Y^2|X]] 
 & \text{X+1 constant given X} \\
 &= E[(X+1)(\mathbb{V}[Y|X]+E[Y|X]^2)] 
 & E[Y^2|X]=\mathbb{V}[Y|X]+E[Y|X]^2 \\
 &= E[(X+1)(3(X+1)+(3(X+1))^2)] 
 & Y|X \sim \text{Poisson}(3(X+1)) \\
 &= (1-p)((0+1)(3(0+1)+(3(0+1))^2) \\
 &+ p((1+1)(3(1+1)+(3(1+1))^2) 
 & X \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p) \\
 &= 12(1-p) + 84p = 12+72p
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
Let $V\sim\mathcal{P}(3)$ and $W\sim \mathcal{P}(6)$. Then, by the Law of Iterated Expectation (aka Law of Total Expectation, Tower Property of Expectation):

$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}\left[(X+1)Y^2\right]
 & = \mathbb P[X=0]\,\Bbb E\left[V^2\right]
    +\mathbb P[X=1]~\mathbb E\left[2W^2\right] \\
 & = (1-p)\,\mathbb{E}\left[V^2\right]
    + 2p\, \mathbb{E}\left[W^2\right]\\
\end{split}
$$

Can you finish this?

Comment: I do not understand, I think I can not finish it. :(

Comment: @NickJr. can you please ask which steps you do not understand and I will explain more. The 1st step uses conditional expectations, the 2nd - just evaluates the probabilities.